# How can I refresh the append data without page refresh jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use ++ in jquery to append data, and I face a problem, I need to refresh the value again if I click other button without refresh page, how can I do that? The var count will increase as I clicked, I want to know if I can start over this count again when I click second button.

```js
var count='1';

$('#good').on('click',function(){
$.ajax({
   url: MyAjaxSearch.ajaxurl,
   type:'POST',
   cache: false,
   data:data,
  success: function(data){   
          count++
       }
  });
  }):

$('#second').on('click',function(){
  //refresh the var count, start from 1 again
  count++
  });
```

Comment: you could just do `current_page=1` inside of your #second click function?

Comment: The question is seriously unclear. In your title you say "...without page refresh..." but in your question you say "...refresh the current page..." Which is it? What would refresh without refresh be? What are you doing in those callbacks other than setting `current_page` (see @deolectrix's point above)?

Comment: Sorry for confusing, I edit my question a little bit. The var count will increase as I clicked, I want to if I can start over this count again when I click second button.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer** *(based on clarification from OP)*:

> I want to if I can start over this count again when I click second button

```
$('#second').on('click',function(){
    //refresh the var count, start from 1 again
    count = 1;
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var count = 1;

$('#good').on('click', function() {
  count++;
  snippet.log("Incremented, count = " + count);
});
$('#second').on('click', function() {
  //refresh the var count, start from 1 again
  count = 1;
  snippet.log("Reset, count = " + count);
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="good" value="Increment">
<input type="button" id="second" value="Reset">
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you wanted the first incremented number to be 1, start with `count = 0`:

**Live Example:**

```js
var count = 0;

$('#good').on('click', function() {
  count++;
  snippet.log("Incremented, count = " + count);
});
$('#second').on('click', function() {
  //refresh the var count, start from 0 again
  count = 0;
  snippet.log("Reset, count = " + count);
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="good" value="Increment">
<input type="button" id="second" value="Reset">
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Original Answer**:

I'm going to take a total guess at it here and say that in your `ajax` callback, you're modifying the page in some way, for instance:

```
$('#good').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: MyAjaxSearch.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            $("selector-for-some-elements").html("new content"); // <===
            current_page++
        }
    });
});
```

And that you want a click on the other element to reset things back to the way they were when the page was first loaded.

**If so**, then you can do something like this (see comments):

```
var current_page = '1';
// *** A variable for remembering the original content
var originalContent;

$('#good').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: MyAjaxSearch.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            // Grab the elements we're going to change
            var elementsToChange = $("selector-for-elements");

            // If we don't have saved content...
            if (!originalContent) {
                // Save the original content
                originalContent = elementsToChange.clone();
            }

            // Modify it
            elementsToChange.html(/*....*/);

            current_page++
        }
    });
});

$('#second').on('click', function() {
    // If we have original content...
    if (originalContent) {
        // Put it back
        $("selector-for-some-elements").replaceWith(originalContent);
        current_page = 1;
    }
});
```

Obviously, many aspects of the above would vary based on what you're actually trying to do, but as you haven't told us what that is, this is the best I can do...

Comment: Thanks for your time. But there is another problem is that it become always 1, no matter how many time I click, it is 1.  I want it count again start from 1.

Comment: @conan: See the live examples. Good luck.